# Transaction Receipt: Confirmation Time

Tags: receipts

I am discovering transaction details on [Ethersan](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x57798a2f763aedb97a252a445d560a0615d33dee425be9692b684809037101e8) and trying to understand how "Timestamp" can be used to calculate how long a particular transaction waited in the pending pool.

In other words, how can I see/compute how long transaction is waited in pending pool before mined by miner?

Comment: you need to run a node with like `--maxpeers 1000` and catch the transaction's timestamp when it first seen by the network. Then you take mesaurements of how quick the block arrived which contains this TX. Do the substraction and that is it

Comment: So what you are saying is that ethescan doesn't provide an API to measure it right?

Comment: I don't know about Etherscan